# Neural Network - Real time prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'll preface this question by saying I'm no expert when it comes to machine learning but I have a fair understanding of neural networks.

Up until this point, the networks I've created to solve trivial problems all use the idea of having a large set of training data, feeding this data through the network and using back propagation to adjust the various weights.

However, how would I approach a problem where data is gathered in real time and a network must use this data during the learning process in order to predict a suitable action to take.

For example, lets say I'm developing fighting game where the player can perform various attacks on enemy mobs. Would it be possible to develop a neural network that could process the moves a player is performing and eventually use this data to predict the player's next action? E.G. The player has performed action **A** twice in a row, using the data gathered about the player previously, the network predicts the player will perform action **B** next.

Unfortunately I don't have sufficient knowledge in the subject to come to a conclusion as to whether or not neural networks are even appropriate for this problem. If this is the case, what techniques could be employed to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite general and so is my answer. Neural networks are able to handle such problems. You should search for methods/keywords like 'online learning using neural networks', 'RNN' (recurrent neural networks), 'LSTM' (long-short term memory). The RNNs and LSTMs are algorithms which are ususally used in order to handle time dependent data using neural networks. 
Some famous (and relatively recent) research in game playing is the AlphaGo program which plays the game of Go, try to read about it and you will get a sense of time dependent machine learning approach.

Answer (score -1):

> "… *what techniques could be employed to solve such a problem?*"

[Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain):

> "*A Markov chain is a stochastic model describing a sequence of possible events in which the probability of each event depends only on the state attained in the previous event".*"

Example:

> "*the data gathered about the player previously*"

```
1 2 3 observed
A A B 25
A A A 12
A B B 10
```

For

> "… *the network predicts the player will perform action B next.*"

match currently observed states `1` and `2`. From this result, state `3` for the record of highest `observed` value represents most common succession. Random selection (chance related to `observed` value) may help avoid over-estimation (would make the "AI" too predictable/manipulatable otherwise). Many [variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) possible.